# Docker unable to start

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

First off, I have never used Docker before, so I am a new user.

I installed the latest Docker version (2.1.0.0), using the default settings, on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine (with virtualisation and Hyper-V enabled). When I start it (Linux containers) I get the following error:

```
Unable to start
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup)
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<Start>b__0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

On the GitHub issue log tab there are multiple people with the same problem, however when I install a previous version (2.0.0.2) I get the same error for the Linux container as above.

Changing to a Windows container does allow Docker Desktop to start, however running this (tagging a Docker image example from https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding) in Windows PowerShell:

```
git clone https://github.com/docker/doodle.git
cd doodle\cheers2019 ; docker build -t jmp111/cheers2019 .
```

gives a different error:

```
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries
```

*What should I change/do differently to get Docker to work?*